# How to connect to remote svn server and retrieve latest revision number

Tags: php, svn

I have a PHP application that runs on my localhost, and I have a remote SVN repository at https://www.assembla.com. I use the SVNTortoise client and it works perfectly, but I'd like to connect to the svn repository via PHP and get the latest revision number, nothing more. I saw other similar questions but in my case the focus is on that i want to connect to a REMOTE repository. How can i run the svn --version command on the remote server and process the response with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy version of Ben answer**

In order to get latest revision for repository (or path inside repo) you can

- Call OS-commmand `svn info URL/TO/REPO` inside PHP, parse answer and extract relevant string (if you have TortoieSVN, you have or can have CLI-version of svn client)

Sample from Assembla's repo

```
>svn info https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-troubleshoot-b/
Path: subversion-troubleshoot-b
URL: https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-troubleshoot-b
Relative URL: ^/
Repository Root: https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-troubleshoot-b
Repository UUID: faaf0d5a-5d64-45f4-9e2a-979cddfce0d6
Revision: 7
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: abream
Last Changed Rev: 7
Last Changed Date: 2012-10-17 22:14:36 +0600 (Ср, 17 окт 2012)
```

You'll use string `Revision` for global repository (or some subtree) Revision-ID

- Get [PHP SVN Client class](http://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/) and use it's [method GetVersion()](http://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/wiki/getVersion)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few of ways to go about this, I don't really use PHP so I'm not going to give you PHP code but I'll tell you how which should be easy enough for you to turn into PHP code.

**Command Line Client**

Realize that `svn --version` does not answer the question you want (it says what version the Subversion client is).  The currently released versions of Subversion do not include a command to ask for the information you want directly (1.9 will include `svn youngest` which does).  So getting this information from the client typical involves doing `svn log -r HEAD $URL` and then parsing the revision number out of that.  You can use `--xml` if you prefer to parse XML.

**Subversion API**

You could use our C API or language bindings to use the [svn_ra_get_latest_revnum()](https://people.apache.org/~brane/svndocs/capi/svn__ra_8h.html#a483f8d91fb6f312d96659180fc4b5b71) function.  You'd need to open an repository access (RA) session and then call the function on that session.  [The implementation of 1.9's new youngest command is an example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/svn/youngest-cmd.c).  However, Subversion provides no API bindings for PHP.  So that's probably not terribly useful to you.

**OPTIONS request against 1.7 and newer HTTP SVN servers**

1.7 and newer servers provide this information in the `SVN-Youngest-Rev` header in response to an OPTIONS request (which clients do to determine what features a server supports).  You just need to request the `activity-collection-set` in the request body with XML.  For example this curl command retrieves the HEAD revision from the ASF repository:

```
curl -si -X OPTIONS --data-binary '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><D:options xmlns:D="DAV:"><D:activity-collection-set></D:activity-collection-set></D:options>' http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf | grep SVN-Youngest-Rev
```

**PROPFIND request against 1.6 and older HTTP SVN servers**

If you don't at least have 1.7 then you'll need to use a PROPFIND request.  First you need to get the version-controlled-configuration URL by doing a PROPFIND request with a `Depth: 0` header and a body like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<propfind xmlns="DAV:">
<prop>
<version-controlled-configuration xmlns="DAV:"/>
</prop>
</propfind>
```

which will give you a response back like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:ns0="DAV:">
<D:response xmlns:lp1="DAV:" xmlns:lp3="http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/">
<D:href>/repos/asf/</D:href>
<D:propstat>
<D:prop>
<lp1:version-controlled-configuration><D:href>/repos/asf/!svn/vcc/default</D:href></lp1:version-controlled-configuration>
</D:prop>
<D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
</D:propstat>
</D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

You want the href in the version-controlled-configuration tag.  You then make a PROPFIND request on that URL relative to the server root you're requesting again with a `Depth: 0` header and the following request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<propfind xmlns="DAV:">
<prop>
<checked-in xmlns="DAV:"/>
</prop></propfind>
```

Which gives you a response like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:ns0="DAV:">
<D:response xmlns:lp1="DAV:" xmlns:lp3="http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/">
<D:href>/repos/asf/!svn/vcc/default</D:href>
<D:propstat>
<D:prop>
<lp1:checked-in><D:href>/repos/asf/!svn/bln/1573025</D:href></lp1:checked-in>
</D:prop>
<D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
</D:propstat>
</D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

The last segment of the href for the checked-in tag is the revision number of HEAD.

**get-latest-rev command against an svnserve server (svn:// protocol)**

I'm not going to go into detail on how to do this directly with the svn:// protocol but you'd want to use the get-latest-rev command that's [documented in the protocol](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_ra_svn/protocol).