# How to get last svn revision number from https url request without local svn client

Tags: curl, svn

I want to ask for HEAD revision number without SVN local client or library integration. I just want to know number of revision for URL to file in my repository. I can download with curl `https://svn_server/some_file.txt?p=12345` my file with revision `12345` but I also need to know what is the latest revision of this file, can I do this with only curl HTTPS requests to SVN server? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22103333) to [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098699/how-to-connect-to-remote-svn-server-and-retrieve-latest-revision-number) has a `curl` call you can use.